# Waving flag effect CSS3 performance issues

Tags: css

I have a set of boxes where each box has an animation:

```
@keyframes pulse {
    0% { transform: scale(1); }
    50% { transform: scale(0); }
    100% { transform: scale(1); }
}
```

In order to create a waving flag effect, I use the `animation-delay` CSS property:

```
.pulsate1 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
}
.pulsate2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.05s;
}
/* And so on up to pulsate20 */
```

These `pulsateN` classes are wrapped around each row of boxes.

There is some occasional flickering using this method, as seen in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cckzd29x/). Is there another better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flickering occurs because CSS doesn't know what to do with scale of 0. Change it to something low like 0.001 and enjoy your [smoothly-waving flag](https://jsfiddle.net/cckzd29x/1/) :)

```
@keyframes pulse {
    0% { transform:  scale(1) translateZ(0); }
    50% { transform: scale(0.001) translateZ(0) }
    100% { transform: scale(1) translateZ(0) }
}
```

(As mentioned by skyline You can add `translateZ(0)` to take advantage of the GPU)

Answer (score 1):

`scale()` is a 2D transformation style. Try adding translateZ(0) or translate3d(0,0,0) to the animation. This will trick the browser into thinking it's doing 3D transformations and will offload the work to the GPU if available. I'm not seeing any flickering on Chrome 49.

```
@keyframes pulse {
    0% { transform: scale(1) translateZ(0); }
    50% { transform: scale(0) translateZ(0); }
    100% { transform: scale(1) translateZ(0); }
}
```

Here's an article explaining the performance benefits of translate3d: https://aerotwist.com/blog/on-translate3d-and-layer-creation-hacks/